# how to match the command line arguments in the batch file

Tags: batch-file

The following script commands check matching the command line argument %1 against the fixed word ala

```
   <code>
        @echo off
    set one=%1
    set two=%2
    If NOT "%one%"=="%one:ala=%" ( echo the first argument contains the word "ala")
    else ( echo no matching ! ) 
    </code>
```

How to replace the fixed word "ala" with an argument %2 from the command line instead.
(because the simple replacement  ala with %2 doesnt work).
Is there any better solution for comparing the argument strings ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delayed expansion to accomplish that type of string replacement.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "one=%~1"
set "two=%~2"
If NOT "%one%"=="!one:%two%=!" (
    echo the first argument contains the word "%two%"
) else ( 
    echo no matching
)
```

And you could also do it without delayed expansion using a technique with the CALL command.

```
@echo off
set "one=%~1"
CALL set "two=%%one:%~2=%%"
If NOT "%one%"=="%two%" (
    echo the first argument contains the word "%two%"
) else ( 
    echo no matching
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
ECHO %~1|FIND "%~2">NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
 ECHO "%~2" NOT found IN "%~1"
) ELSE (
 ECHO "%~2" WAS found IN "%~1"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Use the `find` facility. This avoids `delayedexpansion` but is relatively slow.